# How can I unbind (C-M-x) globally?

Tags: key-bindings

I was trying to bind `(C-M-x)` to `er/expand-region` but I checked the key combination with `(C-h k)` and noticed that it was binded to `eval-defun`. So I tried to unbind it with any of the following commands:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-x") nil)
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-M-x"))
```

But even using any of those won't unbind the key and `(C-M-x)` still will be running `eval-defun`

This is the result after running both commands:

[image: Won't unbind the key]

Comment: note that you don't need to unset a keybinding before applying a new binding. As long as you set your new keybinding in the appropriate keymap, you can leave any other bindings as they are

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate, but I don't have the time now to search for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`eval-defun` is bound to `C-M-x` in `lisp-interaction-mode-map` while `global-set-key` and friends operate on `global-map` which has lower priority than any local key-map.

One way to bind `C-M-x` unconditionally is to use the [bind-key](https://melpa.org/#/bind-key) package which provides `bind-key*` for this purpose:

```
(bind-key* "C-M-x" 'er/expand-region)
```

Comment: Looking at the customoze menu I was surprised that (it seems so) I cannot change the key bindings there.